# Identifying the running time of an playing audio file

Tags: java, android, audio, time

I'm working on a simple audio player that will display how long the audio was playing when I pause/stop it (edit: for example, if I restart the music at 52 seconds, and then pause at 55 seconds, the toast says "3").  As of now, I'm using this:

```
long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
long stopTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Elapsed time was " + ((stopTime - startTime)/1000) + " seconds.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}
```

to display the time difference.  The problem I'm running in to is that startTime is from the first time I hit play, as opposed to the most recent time (just constantly counts up).

```
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Button playMusic;
private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.adele);
    mediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
    mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener(){
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp){
            int duration = mp.getCurrentPosition()/1000;
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Duration:" + duration + " seconds", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

    playMusic = (Button) findViewById(R.id.playButton);
    playMusic.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){

            if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                pauseMusic();
                long stopTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Elapsed time was " + ((stopTime - startTime)/1000) + " seconds.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}
            else {
                startMusic();
            }
        }
    });

    setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
}

public void pauseMusic(){
    if (mediaPlayer !=null){
        mediaPlayer.pause();
        playMusic.setText(getString(R.string.button_start));
    }
}

public void startMusic(){
    if (mediaPlayer != null){
        mediaPlayer.start();
        playMusic.setText(getString(R.string.button_pause));
    }
}

protected void onDestroy(){
    if (mediaPlayer !=null && mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
        mediaPlayer.stop();
        mediaPlayer.release();
        mediaPlayer = null;
    }
    super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly put long startTime and stopTime above onCreate() method.Now,Try adding these lines of code in the onPause() method and change your code like this:

```
public void pauseMusic(){
    if (mediaPlayer !=null){
        mediaPlayer.pause();
        startTime=mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
        playMusic.setText(getString(R.string.button_start));
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Android Geek, I appreciate the help.  When I changed the code it now just always says "Elapsed time was 1490313723 seconds" no matter how short or long I play the song.  I did change your startTime=mp1.... to startTime=mediaPlayer.... because mp1 isnt' a variable in my code and (I think, although I'm new to this) it's meant to be mediaPlayer.

Also, if I'm reading it right, I put the  "long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();" and "long stopTime = System.currentTimeMillis();" right below the "private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;" in my above code.

Comment: Ok, I figured out what I believe you had which was to use the current song position as the toast for how long it's been playing.  This is a great solution.  Unfortunately I think I didn't express what I was wanting very well.  I was trying to ask to be able to time how long between start/pause (i.e. if I restart 52 seconds in to a song, then pause at 55 seconds, the toast says "3").

Comment: I hope it was help to you.I had made edits for the same.

Comment: Yes, thank you and I appreciate the edit!  Do you have any thoughts on what I could do to get it to show how long between start/pauses in the middle of a song?  i.e. If I restart 52 seconds in to the song, then pause at 55 seconds, it will toast "3".  As is, the code would toast "55"

Comment: You mean you want to print 55 seconds in the toast?

Comment: I want to print 3 from that example. So no matter where I start in the song I can pause X amount of seconds later and it will toast X.  Eg restart at 10 seconds, pause at 15, it toasts 5. I then restart again (at 15 seconds), pause at 37, and it toasts 22. And so on.  I'm thinking I need to set an integer when I start/unpause based on current system time, hold it until I pause, where I take the new system time and subtract the old system time which would give me the different. I'm just unsure how to do that via code as I'm very new to this.